# 1 trophy away from platinum

Tags: achievements, ps4, wwe-2k14

I know it's very unlikely but I have 1 trophy left on WWE 2K15 on the Playstation 3 but the console doesn't play discs anymore (only downloaded games). Is there any way at all, not involving a PC off any kind that I can run this game on my Playstation 4 to get this last trophy?

Answer (score 2):

The PlayStation 4 system doesn't support PlayStation 3 software of any kind whether it is disc based or otherwise. One of the major factors in this is that the PlayStation 4s CPU uses the x86 architecture which isn't compatible at all with the Cell Processor inside the PlayStation 3 and thus is unable to support PlayStation 3 software without emulation which currently isn't an option and is very unlikely to be in the future.

The only glimmer of hope is if the game is released as part of PlayStation Now but I'm not sure whether that will be the case or not.

Edit: I have checked the current list of supported PlayStation Now games ([Source](http://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/psnow/subscriptions/)) and WWE 2K15 isn't on the list as of yet.

Comment: Thank you... I knew it was a long shot but thought I'd get a more professional view

Comment: @Nayphan I have checked the list of current PlayStation Now games and WWE2K15 is not supported at this time but it is possible that support may be added in the future.